# Strange DbEntityValidationException on calling SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am busy developing a ASP.net web application using MVC4 and ran into this strange error when trying to save some changes to the db. This code is in one of my controllers. The below code causes a DbEntityValidationException when _db.Save() is called which in turn calls SaveChanges(). I am working with EntityFramework V5.

```
Document document = _db.Documents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == doc.ID);
if (document != null)
{
    document.Location = idPath;
    _db.Save();
}
```

The exception message:

[image]

But: When I use the following code I get no exception and the path gets saved to the db successfully.

```
Document document = _db.Documents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == doc.ID);
if (document != null)
{
    // Needed for SaveChanges to work
    var x = document.Type;

    document.Location = idPath;
    _db.Save();
}
```

Why would this happen? Is it maybe because my Documents collection is of type List? Note that I have found that the error is caused by the Type property.

Below is the structure of my Document class:

```
[Table("Document")]
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Location { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual DocumentType Type { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual HttpPostedFileBase File{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in text format, instead of screenshots?

Comment: Also, the exact error message.

Comment: On a separate note, do you NEED to use SingleOrDefault()?  FirstOrDefault() is far more efficient as long as you don't have to ensure that it is the only record that  matches (because of primary key constraints, ect).

Comment: Hi, I will post the text and error now. Basically the error only says "The Type field is required." @David Thanks I will change it to FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because of `Lazy Loading`.

In fact, by calling this line:

```
Document document = _db.Documents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == doc.ID);
```

You get only the scalar properties of the `Document` entity and its navigation properties remain null...! (Set a break point and look).

However, when you call this line:

```
var x = document.Type;
```

You force the EF to query the database to fetch the `Type` navigation property into the memory and attach it to the dbcontext. Indeed it's a normal behavior, Lazy loading! - don't get anything unless that's really needed.

So, as you see, It's of course not a strange error! it's just a side effect of lazy loading...

Comment: If you inspect navigation properties with the debugger, doesn't it trigger EF to load the property?  I think if he does this test it could be confusing :)

Answer (score 2):

`public virtual DocumentType Type` is required as per your entity definition, however in your first example, `Type` would be null if eager loading is not enabled (which is my assumption).

The reason your second example works is because `Type` is being lazy loaded on this line `var x = document.Type;`.  You could either turn eager loading on, or use the `.Include()` to selectively load the `Type` property.

Check out this link for info about the various types of EF loading related entities.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx